# I am using xcode 9. how to create framework with xib files inside?

Tags: ios, frameworks, xib

I want to create a framework that includes xib.

Do I have to use the bundle?

If so, should I distribute the bundle file and the .framework file when I deploy?

The framework I created seems a bit crude.

Do you have any examples of frameworks including xib files?

Thank you for your reply. :)

Comment: To create a ‘Common.xib‘ selecting ‘File -> New -> File‘, selecting ‘View‘ as the iOS user interface file type, and name the file.

Answer (score 1):

Framework will automatically wrap your resource files (xcassets, images, storyboard, xib) into bundle inside the `.framework` file after compile, you dont really need to do anything.

Static library then you will have to create bundle target and pack it yourself.